# JDBC UnableToExecuteStatementException for creating table for testing

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I'm using http://wakandan.github.io/2015/09/21/setup-dropwizard-testing-for-dao.html guide for testing dao

I setup my `DataSourceFactory` as

```
DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DataSourceFactory();
dataSourceFactory.setDriverClass( "org.h2.Driver" );
dataSourceFactory.setUrl( "jdbc:h2:mem:test-%s;MODE=MySQL;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MY_SCHEMA" );
dataSourceFactory.setUser( "sa" );
dataSourceFactory.setPassword( "" );
return dataSourceFactory;
```

My `sql` file looks like

```
USE my_schema;

CREATE TABLE users (
    AutoId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

I have used these sql before using `mysql -uroot my_schema < 0001.sql` and so on and they work fine.

Using

USE my_schema;

```
handle.begin();
    handle.createScript(FixtureHelpers.fixture("schema/0001.sql"))
        .execute();
    //and so on
    handle.commit()
```

I get

> org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException:
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Syntax error in SQL statement
>   "CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.USERS (   AUTOID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
>   AUTO_INCREMENT ... ) ENGINE = INNODB, DEFAULT CHARSET = UTF8 ";
>   expected "USING, ,, )";

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try omitting the `ENGINE = InnoDB` clause in your CREATE TABLE statement That is specific to MySQL itself and the MySQL compatibility mode of H2 doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: @GordThompson makes sense. But how would I go about using the same `.sql` files that are used to bootup my actual db? I don't want to keep two versions of the sql, one for actual db, and one for testing

Comment: If you run `SHOW ENGINES` against your MySQL server and it returns `Engine: InnoDB  Support: DEFAULT` then you can simply omit the `ENGINE=InnoDB` clause in your CREATE TABLE statement altogether.